# Is it likely that two neighbors having the same ISP will have the same public IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, isp

Imagine the following scenario: there is a big building, with hundreds of apartments, and every apartment uses the same ISP. Each apartment has their own router.

If a website logs every IP address, is it likely that two different apartments accessing the website will result in the same IP being logged?

In other words, assuming nobody changes their IP manually with some trick, TOR, etc., how safe it is to assume that two connections with the same public IP to my website come from the same apartment?

Comment: Lots of ISPs are now using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: So what is your real question? This all reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) question. Are you having problems with your Internet connection and you believe a common IP address is the cause?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 my question is just hypothetical as I wrote. It is based on a discussion about whether a certain assumption about IPs is valid or not, and how likely it is for the assumption to be wrong. I am not coding anything or designing any sort of project.

Comment: @BernardoSubercaseaux Makes sense. The idea IP addresses equate to one person is truly an “old wive’s tale” nowadays… And in general it was never a good way to ID someone. If I take my MacBook and walk around the neighborhood and connect to various free WiFi access points, I get different I addresses each time without doing anything other than move around and connect to different WiFi access points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they're behind [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) they will all have the same IP address. Otherwise it's the same chance as any two random customers of that ISP.

Basically, you cannot use IP address as a reliable identification method.

Comment: “Basically, you cannot use IP address as a reliable identification method.” Additionally, many IP addresses are not static. So the days of seeing an IP address and equating that to a sole person or entity are long gone. In fact it was never reliable if you think about it: ISPs changing IP addresses during maintenance, modem power cycling, etc… etc… I happen to have a static IP address by coincidence from my ISP. It has not changed in years. But the second my ISP decides to change it, that’s that. Not much I can do unless I want to pay $$$ for a static IP address… Which I have no need to do.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - yup, mine has by complete 'accident' only changed once in 10 years. Irritatingly, because of a complete national area/subnet reshuffle, everything I did online for about 2 weeks thought i lived in Bristol, about 140 miles from my home in London, which caused some confusion ;))

Answer (score 6):

If two connections come from a single public IP, all you know without further information is that they probably share a router.

Any of the following is possible; the two connections can:

- come from the same computer,
- come from different computers in the same house,
- come from different apartments in a building that shares a router,
- come from a wide number of possible people behind a CGNAT setup,
- come from the same or different computers that are sharing the same public Wifi access point,
- come from a hacked or purposefully-configured system that is proxying for other computers anywhere else in the Internet.

IP is a dumb protocol by design so it can operate as fast as possible, capacity added as flexibly as possible, and be bypassed/shunted elsewhere as fast as possible in the event of problems.

IP addresses are not meant to identify people, but interfaces.

You need additional mechanisms to authenticate and secure IP based transport, and if an IP network is accessible to the public, prepare for abusive situations you can't place blame at specific individuals immediately--like DDoS, etc.